# Help converting PHP eregi to preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am wondering if someone could please help me convert a piece of PHP code that is now deprecated.

Here is the single line I am trying to convert:

```
eregi("<text>(.*)TYPE[ \r\n]*(OF|or)[ \r\n]*REPORTING[ \r\n]*PERSON",$string,$outp);
```

When I convert to the following:

```
preg_match("/<text>(.*)TYPE[ \r\n]*(OF|or)[ \r\n]*REPORTING[ \r\n]*PERSON/i",$string,$outp);
```

It matched nothing. The original eregi function works well.

Comment: I doubt anyone on SO will just do it for you. But, not to be a sphincter, I would advise to split the expression into chunks and convert them one by one.

Comment: Check out http://refiddle.com/ for your regex debugging needs. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `/is` flag at the end of the regex.

The reason is that the preg_ function does not match linebreaks with `.*`, whereas the old ereg functions would do that per default.

Otherwise your regular expression should work unchanged with PCRE.